# merging Python dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, merge

I am trying to merge the following python dictionaries as follow:

```
dict1= {'paul':100, 'john':80, 'ted':34, 'herve':10}
dict2 = {'paul':'a', 'john':'b', 'ted':'c', 'peter':'d'}

output = {'paul':[100,'a'],
          'john':[80, 'b'],
          'ted':[34,'c'],
          'peter':[None, 'd'],
          'herve':[10, None]}
```

I wish to keep all keys from both dictionaries.
Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: [@rcreswick's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression/44512#44512) to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression">this question</a> should suit your needs.

Comment: A little formatting would go a long way here.  Try editing your question:  select the code and click the "101 010" button in the edit window.  Also, separate dict1 & dict2 into two separate lines.

Comment: **See also:** [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415785/merging-several-python-dictionaries)

Answer (score 22):

```
output = {k: [dict1[k], dict2.get(k)] for k in dict1}
output.update({k: [None, dict2[k]] for k in dict2 if k not in dict1})
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this works? What is the object being passed to `dict()` and `update()`? Is it a generator?

Comment: @Heisenberg, they're **generator expressions** (AKA "genexp"s), the generator equivalent of "list comprehensions" (AKA "listcomp"s) -- a handy way to make a generator in-line (saves transient use of memory compared to the equivalent listcomp, if the list is not needed later -- as it wouldn't be here since `dict` and `update` both just need some kind of iterator yielding 2-item tuples taken as `(key, value)`).

Answer (score 17):

This will work:

```
{k: [dict1.get(k), dict2.get(k)] for k in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys())}
```

Output:

```
{'john': [80, 'b'], 'paul': [100, 'a'], 'peter': [None, 'd'], 'ted': [34, 'c'], 'herve': [10, None]}
```

Answer (score 9):

In **Python2.7** or **Python3.1** you can easily generalise to work with any number of dictionaries using a combination of list, set and dict comprehensions!

```
>>> dict1 = {'paul':100, 'john':80, 'ted':34, 'herve':10}
>>> dict2 = {'paul':'a', 'john':'b', 'ted':'c', 'peter':'d'}
>>> dicts = dict1,dict2
>>> {k:[d.get(k) for d in dicts] for k in {k for d in dicts for k in d}}
{'john': [80, 'b'], 'paul': [100, 'a'], 'peter': [None, 'd'], 'ted': [34, 'c'], 'herve': [10, None]}
```

**Python2.6** doesn't have set comprehensions or dict comprehensions

```
>>> dict1 = {'paul':100, 'john':80, 'ted':34, 'herve':10}
>>> dict2 = {'paul':'a', 'john':'b', 'ted':'c', 'peter':'d'}
>>> dicts = dict1,dict2
>>> dict((k,[d.get(k) for d in dicts]) for k in set(k for d in dicts for k in d))
{'john': [80, 'b'], 'paul': [100, 'a'], 'peter': [None, 'd'], 'ted': [34, 'c'], 'herve': [10, None]}
```

Comment: py3k also has dict comprehensions ;)

Comment: @SilentGhost, I was just thinking that too. Imagine my surprise when I saw your comment :) It's quite succinct in 3.1 now

Answer (score 2):

**In Python3.1,**

```
output = {k:[dict1.get(k),dict2.get(k)] for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}
```

**In Python2.6,**

```
output = dict((k,[dict1.get(k),dict2.get(k)]) for k in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) (from itertools) you can avoid the list/dict/set comprehension with:

```
dict(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda d: d.items(), list_of_dicts])))
```

It can be more or less convenient and readable than double comprehension, depending on your personal preference.