# Merge several Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have to merge list of python dictionary. For eg:

```
dicts[0] = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dicts[1] = {'a':1, 'd':2, 'c':'foo'}
dicts[2] = {'e':57,'c':3}

super_dict = {'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[3,'foo'], 'd':[2], 'e':[57]}
```

I wrote the following code:

```
super_dict = {}
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if super_dict.get(k) is None:
            super_dict[k] = []
        if v not in super_dict.get(k):
            super_dict[k].append(v)
```

*Can it be presented more elegantly / optimized?*

**Note**
I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365921/merging-python-dictionaries) on SO but its about merging exactly 2 dictionaries.

Comment: **See also**: [merge nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge)

Comment: **See also:** [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365921/merging-python-dictionaries)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can iterate over the dictionaries directly -- no need to use `range`. The `setdefault` method of dict looks up a key, and returns the value if found. If not found, it returns a default, and also assigns that default to the key.

```
super_dict = {}
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():  # d.items() in Python 3+
        super_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Also, you might consider using a `defaultdict`. This just automates `setdefault` by calling a function to return a default value when a key isn't found.

```
import collections
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():  # d.items() in Python 3+
        super_dict[k].append(v)
```

Also, as [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415875/577088) astutely observed, you seem to want no duplication of values in your lists. In that case, `set` gets you what you want:

```
import collections
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():  # d.items() in Python 3+
        super_dict[k].add(v)
```

Comment: Or if you are looking for a one-liner, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649266/6568097

Answer (score 38):

you can use this behaviour of dict. (a bit elegant)

```py
 a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
 b = {'d':1, 'e':2, 'f':3}
 c = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
 merge = {**a, **b, **c}
 print(merge) # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 2, 'f': 3, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

and you are good to go :)

Comment: Your solution replaces values of keys, instead of combining them in a list.
This is the result of your solution: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 57}`

Comment: In my case, keys were unique in each dict and this was what I exactly wanted. Thanks!

Comment: this method removes duplicate items in dictionary.

Comment: But how do you make in generic for an unknown number of dictionaries?

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 37):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},
         {'a':1, 'd':2, 'c':'foo'},
         {'e':57, 'c':3} ]

super_dict = defaultdict(set)  # uses set to avoid duplicates

for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():  # use d.iteritems() in python 2
        super_dict[k].add(v)
```

Comment: +1: This seems to be exactly what the question was asking for (unique elements in the values), done in a relatively clear and certainly efficient way (the dictionaries are gone through a single time, and the built-in set makes keeping only unique elements fast).

Answer (score 15):

Merge the keys of all dicts, and for each key assemble the list of values:

```
super_dict = {}
for k in set(k for d in dicts for k in d):
    super_dict[k] = [d[k] for d in dicts if k in d]
```

The expression `set(k for d in dicts for k in d)` builds a set of all unique keys of all dictionaries.  For each of these unique keys, we use the list comprehension `[d[k] for d in dicts if k in d]` to build the list of values from all dicts for this key.

Since you only seem to one the *unique* value of each key, you might want to use sets instead:

```
super_dict = {}
for k in set(k for d in dicts for k in d):
    super_dict[k] = set(d[k] for d in dicts if k in d)
```

Comment: Pretty solid. I think it could be improved with an explanation.

Comment: @Edwin: Thanks, I added a bit of explanation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach minor thing -- with the second version, we get a dict of sets instead of a dict of lists -- easily handled if it matters to OP.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Semantically, sets seem to be what the OP wants.  So it's a feature of that code, not a bug.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: True, I may be taking the question too literally.

Comment: This is compact, it does the job, but is also generally wasteful in terms of number of operations done. senderle's answer goes through the dictionaries a smaller number of times.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like most of the answers using comprehensions are not all that readable. In case any gets lost in the mess of answers above this might be helpful (although extremely late...). Just loop over the items of each dict and place them in a separate one.

```
super_dict = {key:val for d in dicts for key,val in d.items()}
```

Comment: The OP wanted both `'c'` values preserved: `{'c':[3,'foo']}`.

Answer (score 6):

When the value of the keys are in list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

    dicts = [{'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[3]},
             {'a':[11], 'd':[2], 'c':['foo']},
             {'e':[57], 'c':[3], "a": [1]} ]

super_dict = defaultdict(list)  # uses set to avoid duplicates

for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():  # use d.iteritems() in python 2
        super_dict[k] = list(set(super_dict[k] + v))

combined_dict = {}

for elem in super_dict.keys():
    combined_dict[elem] = super_dict[elem]

combined_dict
## output: {'a': [1, 11], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 'foo'], 'd': [2], 'e': [57]}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a very easy to go solution without any imports.
I use the dict.update() method.
But sadly it will overwrite, if same key appears in more than one dictionary, then the most recently merged dict's value will appear in the output.

```
dict1 = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7}
dict2 = {'Sex': 'female' }
dict3 = {'Status': 'single', 'Age': 27}
dict4 = {'Occupation':'nurse', 'Wage': 3000}

def mergedict(*args):
    output = {}
    for arg in args:
        output.update(arg)
    return output
    
print(mergedict(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4))
```

The **output** is this:

> {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 27, 'Sex': 'female', 'Status': 'single', 'Occupation': 'nurse', 'Wage': 3000}

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit more elegant:

```
super_dict = {}
for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        l=super_dict.setdefault(k,[])
        if v not in l:
            l.append(v)
```

UPDATE: made change suggested by Sven

UPDATE: changed to avoid duplicates (thanks Marcin and Steven)

Comment: Nice.  I'd suggest `for d in dicts:` instead of `for i in xrange(len(dicts))`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Nice, i made that change.

Comment: Minor nit.  Duplicates on key `'c'`: `[3, 'foo', 3]`.  OP's example code shows that the `3` does not repeat.

Comment: ok.  correction.  I shouldn't have said the "OP's example code", I should have said the OP's example *dictionary*: `super_dict = {'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[3,'foo'], 'd':[2], 'e':[57]}`

Comment: `if v not in l` is asymptotically very slow compared to using sets instead of lists. You are essentially emulating sets where Python offers them for free…

Answer (score 3):

Never forget that the standard libraries have a wealth of tools for dealing with dicts and iteration:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
super_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in dicts):
    if v not in super_dict[k]: super_dict[k].append(v)
```

Note that the `if v not in super_dict[k]` can be avoided by using `defaultdict(set)` as per Steven Rumbalski's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a more modern and concise approach for those who use python 3.3 or later versions is the use of `ChainMap` from the `collections` module.

```py
from collections import ChainMap

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
d2 = {'c': 2}
d3 = {'d': 7, 'a': 9}
d4 = {}
combo = dict(ChainMap(d1, d2, d3, d4))
# {'d': 7, 'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
```

For a larger collection of dict objects then star operator works

```py
dict(ChainMap(*dict_collection))
```

Note that the resulting dictionary seems to only keep the value of the first key it encounters in the ordered collection and ignores any further duplicates.

Comment: I think the question is looking to have `'a': [1, 9]`, so this is wrong

Comment: @Y4RD13 I have noted that in the last sentence before your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the keys in which you are interested are at the same nested level, you can recursively traverse each dictionary and create a new dictionary using that key, effectively merging them.

```
merged = {}
for d in dicts:
    def walk(d,merge):
        for key, item in d.items():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                merge.setdefault(key, {})
                walk(item, merge[key])
            else:
                merge.setdefault(key, [])
                merge[key].append(item)
    walk(d,merged)
```

For example, say you have the following dictionaries you want to merge.

```
dicts = [{'A': {'A1': {'FOO': [1,2,3]}}},
         {'A': {'A1': {'A2': {'BOO': [4,5,6]}}}},
         {'A': {'A1': {'FOO': [7,8]}}},
         {'B': {'B1': {'COO': [9]}}},
         {'B': {'B2': {'DOO': [10,11,12]}}},
         {'C': {'C1': {'C2': {'POO':[13,14,15]}}}},
         {'C': {'C1': {'ROO': [16,17]}}}]
```

Using the key at each level, you should get something like this:

```
{'A': {'A1': {'FOO': [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8]], 
              'A2': {'BOO': [[4, 5, 6]]}}},
 'B': {'B1': {'COO': [[9]]}, 
       'B2': {'DOO': [[10, 11, 12]]}},
 'C': {'C1': {'C2': {'POO': [[13, 14, 15]]}, 
              'ROO': [[16, 17]]}}}
```

Note: I assume the leaf at each branch is a list of some kind, but you can obviously change the logic to do whatever is necessary for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

For a oneliner, the following could be used:

`{key: {d[key] for d in dicts if key in d} for key in {key for d in dicts for key in d}}`

although readibility would benefit from naming the combined key set:

```
combined_key_set = {key for d in dicts for key in d}
super_dict = {key: {d[key] for d in dicts if key in d} for key in combined_key_set}
```

Elegance can be debated but personally I prefer comprehensions over for loops. :)

(The dictionary and set comprehensions are available in [Python 2.7/3.1](http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features) and newer.)

Answer (score 1):

python 3.x *(reduce is builtin for python 2.x, so no need to import if in 2.x)*

```
import operator
from functools import operator.add

a = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]

dict(reduce(operator.add, map(list,(map(dict.items, a))))
```

`map(dict.items, a)` # converts to list of key, value iterators

`map(list, ...` # converts to iterator equivalent of [[[a, 1]], [[b, 2]], [[c, 3],[d,4]]]

`reduce(operator.add, ...` # reduces the multiple list down to a single list

Comment: I like this answer, and have posted a [newer simpler version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74355295/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a more recent enhancement over the [prior answer by ElbowPipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099326/), using [newer syntax introduced in Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators) for merging dictionaries. Note that this answer does not merge conflicting values into a list!

```py
> import functools
> import operator

> functools.reduce(operator.or_, [{0:1}, {2:3, 4:5}, {2:6}])

{0: 1, 2: 6, 4: 5}
```

Comment: This would also work: `functools.reduce(dict.__or__, dicts)`

Comment: I have not checked, but I think reduce would be quadratic in case of many dicts. 

So an alternative (which is less compact), but with linear time.
`dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(foo.items() for foo in dicts))`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to @senderle proposed, but instead of for loop I used map

```
super_dict = defaultdict(set)
map(lambda y: map(lambda x: super_dict[x].add(y[x]), y), dicts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of defaultdict is good, this also can be done with the use of itertools.groupby.

```
import itertools
# output all dict items, and sort them by key
dicts_ele = sorted( ( item for d in dicts for item in d.items() ), key = lambda x: x[0] )
# groups items by key
ele_groups = itertools.groupby( dicts_ele, key = lambda x: x[0] )
# iterates over groups and get item value
merged = { k: set( v[1] for v in grouped ) for k, grouped in ele_groups }
```

and obviously, you can merge this block of code into one-line style

```
merged = {
    k: set( v[1] for v in grouped )
    for k, grouped in (
        itertools.groupby(
            sorted(
                ( item for d in dicts for item in d.items() ),
                key = lambda x: x[0]
            ),
            key = lambda x: x[0]
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm a bit late to the game but I did it in 2 lines with no dependencies beyond python itself:

```
flatten = lambda *c: (b for a in c for b in (flatten(*a) if isinstance(a, (tuple, list)) else (a,)))
o = reduce(lambda d1,d2: dict((k, list(flatten([d1.get(k), d2.get(k)]))) for k in set(d1.keys() + d2.keys())), dicts)
# output:
# {'a': [1, 1, None], 'c': [3, 'foo', 3], 'b': [2, None, None], 'e': [None, 57], 'd': [None, 2, None]}
```

Though if you don't care about nested lists, then:

```
o2 = reduce(lambda d1,d2: dict((k, [d1.get(k), d2.get(k)]) for k in set(d1.keys() + d2.keys())), dicts)
# output:
# {'a': [[1, 1], None], 'c': [[3, 'foo'], 3], 'b': [[2, None], None], 'e': [None, 57], 'd': [[None, 2], None]}
```

Comment: `None` values should not be created, as per the question.