# Combine values of same keys in a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries in the following format:

```
foo = [
    {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'},
    {'a': 'j', 'c': 'z'}
]
```

I want to group this list of dictionaries into a single dictionary, like:

```
bar = {
    'a': ['x', 'j'],
    'b': ['y', None],
    'c': ['z', 'z']
}
```

What I've currently done is, looping through all the dicts in `foo` and create a list of keys and then looping again over the same to create `bar`. I wonder whether there is a simpler way to accomplish this. Can anyone help?

Comment: does `foo` have only 2 dicts or just any number?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It can have more than two.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
bar = {
    k: [d.get(k) for d in foo]
    for k in set().union(*foo)
}
```

Things to google:

- python list comprehension
- python dict comprehension
- python star
- python dict get
- python set union

Comment: good solution, could have come with some explanations. I like the `set().union(*foo)` part.

Comment: @Alex Hall  +1 for adding google  search tips

Comment: Is there a reason to use `d.get(k)` instead of `d[k]`? Edit: Found the answer: [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405/774575)

Comment: @mins - use ```d.get(k)``` - because the key ```k``` might not exist.

Answer (score 11):

I am just going to complement [Alex Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2482744/alex-hall) solution here, so that it does not return a lot of "None" values:

```py
def merge_dictionary_list(dict_list):
  return {
    k: [d.get(k) for d in dict_list if k in d] # explanation A
    for k in set().union(*dict_list) # explanation B
  }
```

Explanation:

- The whole thing inside `{}` is a dictionary comprehension
- **Explanation A**: Go through all elements in dictionary list and get values for current key `k` if the current dictionary (`d`) being evaluated actually has that key.

**OBS:** Without the `if k in d` expression there could be a bunch of `None`
values appended to the arrays in case the list of dictionaries
contains different types of keys.

- **Explanation B**: gets all keys from list of dictionary and unite them distinctly by using `set().union`. After all we can only have distinct elements in set data structure.

If you want to do it the traditional way, just go with:

```py
def merge_list_of_dictionaries(dict_list):
  new_dict = {}
  for d in dict_list:
    for d_key in d:
      if d_key not in new_dict:
        new_dict[d_key] = []
      new_dict[d_key].append(d[d_key])
  return new_dict
```

I think the first solution looks more elegant, but the second one is more legible/readable.

Kind Regards :)

Answer (score 4):

I would do this in two steps:

1. Collect all keys into a single iterable:

   ```
   >>> import operator
   >>> from functools import reduce
   >>> all_keys = reduce(operator.or_, (d.keys() for d in foo))
   >>> all_keys
   {'a', 'b', 'c'}
   ```
2. Use a dict comprehension to create the desired result:

   ```
   >>> bar = {key: [d.get(key) for d in foo] for key in all_keys}
   >>> bar
   {'a': ['x', 'j'], 'b': ['y', None], 'c': ['z', 'z']}
   ```

Comment: good one. May I suggest `all_keys = reduce(operator.or_, map(dict.keys,foo))` ?

Comment: This is Python 3 only.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's a viable alternative. The reason why I chose to avoid `map` is because it forces me to explicitly state the class - `dict.keys`. The generator expression on the other hand would also work with dict subclasses or any other objects that have a `.keys()` function.

Comment: @AlexHall Maybe. If the subclass has overriden the `keys` function, who knows what would happen. But let's drop this discussion; in the end the differences are so minor that it comes down to preference.

Comment: You could also do `set(chain.from_iterable(foo))` to get a set of all keys.