# How to do Python one liner to create a dict from result set

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

What I have:

```
d1=[{'type':'fruit','name':'apple'},{'type':'fruit','name':'orange'},{'type':'vehicle','name':'car'},{'type':'vehicle','name':'bike'}]
```

What I did:

```
res=[{i['type']:i['name']} for i in d1]
```

What I received:

```
res=>[{'fruit': 'apple'}, {'fruit': 'orange'}, {'vehicle': 'car'}, {'vehicle': 'bike'}]
```

But What I need:

```
res=>{'fruit': ['apple','orange'], 'vehicle': ['car','bike']}
```

How to achieve this? thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
This will be more readable. But I want one liner instead!

```
u={}
for i in d1:
    if u.get(i['type']):
        u[i['type']].append(i['name'])
    else:
        u[i['type']]=[i['name']]
```

Comment: I strongly recommend avoiding one-liners for readability. However, if you really need it, @deceze 's answer is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this oneliner:

```
d1=[{'type':'vehicle','name':'car'},{'type':'fruit','name':'apple'},{'type':'fruit','name':'orange'},{'type':'vehicle','name':'bike'}]

res = {
    k: [d.get('name') for d in d1 if k in d.values()]
    for k in set(list(map(lambda x: x['type'],d1)))
}

print(res)
```

Or maybe you could try this "two-liner":

```
d1=[{'type':'fruit','name':'apple'},{'type':'fruit','name':'orange'},{'type':'vehicle','name':'car'},{'type':'vehicle','name':'bike'}]

temp=[{d['type']:d['name']} for d in d1]
res = {k: list(filter(None,[d.get(k) for d in temp]))
    for k in set().union(*temp)
}
print(res)
```

Second solution is based on [Alex Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649266/13676202).

Outputs:

```
{'vehicle': ['car', 'bike'], 'fruit': ['apple', 'orange']}
```

Answer (score 3):

As for a one-liner, that would have to be something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = {k: list(map(itemgetter('name'), v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(d1, key=itemgetter('type')), itemgetter('type'))}
```

Which I think is pretty complicated, but there you go…

Comment: Nice, I was trying something similar and didn't know about itemgetter (learned something!). This actually looks worse than it is when you go through it, but I agree with the general sentiment of every one but OP that the one liner is not really efficient nor readable.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer not to use a oneliner here. Something like this maybe

```
x = {}
for item in d1:
    x.setdefault(item['type'], []).append(item['name'])
```

As for me it's a bit more readable

If you really insist on oneliner, you can do something like this. But this would produce en empty list like `[None, None]`, which will be thrown away

```
x = {}
[x.setdefault(item['type'], []).append(item['name']) for item in d1]
```

Comment: Readable code means I can do like this,
u={}
for i in d1:
 if u.get(i['type']):
  u[i['type']].append(i['name'])
 else:
  u[i['type']]=[i['name']]

But I want efficient one liner

Comment: @Vanjith You can replace the `if..else` with the demonstrated `setdefault`, which makes that much simpler.

Comment: The onliner recommended is [very anti-Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/4985099)