# Python - How to merge multiple dictionaries that exist in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have in my code a list with multiple dictionaries in it (at the moment I have a specific number of dictionaries, but **I need the program to work for any n numbers of dictionaries**).

For example, let say I have 3 dictionaries to simplify:

What I have:

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'b':4, 'c': 5, 'd': 6}, {'c':7, 'd': 8, 'e': 9}]
```

what I need:

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 15, 'd': 14, 'e': 9}]
```

or

```
my_list = {'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 15, 'd': 14, 'e': 9}
```

(It's essentially the same thing, isn't it?)

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merging several python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415785/merging-several-python-dictionaries)

Comment: @Woot4Moo This doesn't answer my question because in the thread that you linked the values doesn't add up together

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum()` and `collections.Counter`:

```
In [90]: sum(map(Counter, my_list), Counter())
Out[90]: Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 15, 'd': 14, 'e': 9})
```

Also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717000/2867928 for more information.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer,
But you see, I am quite a newbie and I don't quite understand these `In [90]` and  `Out[90]` .
Forgive my ignorance but could you please elaborate?

Comment: @amam3214 Read the link that I've posted and the documentation for `sum` and `map` functions. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html