# Running a loop where each iteration returns a dict. How best to combine them into one?

Tags: python

I've found several SO posts on similar questions but I'm maybe overthinking my problem.

I'm running a loop. Each iteration returns a dict with the same keys and their own values. I'd like to combine them into a new master dict.

On each loop iteration I can save the results to a list

```
store_response = [] # will store the results of each iteration here
myloop:
    code here...
    store_response.append(iresponse.copy())
```

Or I can do:

```
store_response = {} # will store the results of each iteration here
myloop:
    code here...
    store_response[page_token] = iresponse  # store this iteration and call it whatever string page_token currently is
```

So I can return either a list of dicts or dict of dicts.

My question is, how can I combine them into just one dict?
Tried several for loops but keep hitting errors e.g.:

```
for d in store_response:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        test[key].append(value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Here is how the variable looks in PyCharms variables pane, currently in list form but I could make it a dict:
[image]

How can I take each dict within store response and create a single master dict?

Comment: If you want them in one dictionary, should the values be a list then for a given key?

Comment: @rvd the format should be the same as the child elements in the screen. So the master dict should match e.g. `store_response[0]` in terms of structure. Does that asnwer your question?

Comment: So the keys should just be 0, 1, ... and the values are the child `dict`s seen here?

Comment: Ah wait. Actually it's the reports. The master dict should just have one key for reports which is the combination of the other 5

Comment: Ok - I will respond with an answer then below.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` - Which Python version?  Try [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merging several python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415785/merging-several-python-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 3, and in Python 3 `iteritems` has been removed use `items` instead.

```py
for d in store_response:
    for key, value in d.items():
        test.setdefault(key, [])
        test[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with ```for d in store_response:
    for key, value in d.items():
        test[key].append(value)
        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'reports'```
Any ideas?

Comment: @DoughFir, what is `test`. I guess this is a dictionary which values are lists. This means that there is no element associated with the key `'reports'`.

Comment: Test is currently an empty dict ```{}```. I created just to try to house a new master dict

Comment: @DougFir, I just edited my answer. Use `setdefault` to give a default value (in this case an empty list), when it doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks I tried that: ```for d in store_response:
    for key, value in d.items():
        test.setdefault(key, default=[])
        test[key].append(value)
        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: setdefault() takes no keyword arguments```

Comment: @DoughFir, updated, just remove the keyword argument `default`.

Comment: Thanks that ran but the result is not what I expected. After running that test is a dict that contains one item 'reports' and reports is a list of the original dicts. What I meant was that there would no longer be 5 nested dicts just one 'reports' that contains the accumulated values of the original 5?

Comment: @DougFir, This is a bit different from what you asked originally.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear I appreciate the time you put in to answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200180/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-doug-fir).

Answer (score 1):

You could try a pattern like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
store_response = defaultdict(list)
for _ in loop:
    # Assuming the loop provides the key and value
    store_response[key].append(value)
```

This will result in a `dict` with one key that collapses all values for that key as a list (in your use case since your dictionaries only have one key - this solution works for arbitrarily many keys like `'reports'`).