# Best way to combine a list of dicts into one dict in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I've been working with a long list of dicts for a while and can't seem to wrap my head around how to sort it the way I'd like. Here's a shorter example:

```
artist_movement = [
{'movement': 'Abstract Expressionism', 'artist': 'William Baziotes'}, 
{'movement': 'Modern Art', 'artist': 'Alexander Calder'}, 
{'movement': 'Abstract Expressionism', 'artist': 'Grace Hartigan'},
{'movement': 'Cubism', 'artist': 'Pablo Picasso'}, 
{'movement': 'Cubism', 'artist': 'Peter Blume'}, 
{'movement': 'Abstract Expressionism', 'artist': 'Norman Wilfred Lewis'},
{'movement': 'Modern Art', 'artist': 'Lucian Freud'}
]
```

I'd like to sort the artists by movement in in a similar way to this:

```
artist_by_movement = [
{'Abstract Expressionism':['William Baziotes', 'Grace Hartigan', 'Norman Wilfred Lewis']},
{'Modern Art':['Alexander Calder', 'Lucian Freud']},
{'Cubism':['Peter Blume', 'Pablo Picasso']}
]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you looked on SO/google for something similar? Merging dicts comes up a lot...

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365921/merging-python-dictionaries) help?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I looked for a few hours for a good explanation that related directly to my problem (merging a list of dicts by key) but didn't find anything.

Comment: Actually, that link may help. I'll have another go at it. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck with it:)

Comment: Just a note that your artists_by_movement dictionary doesn't work as written. You have multiple values for the same key, which overwrite each other.

Comment: @Reid - I suppose a nested dictionary would work instead?

Comment: @djangonoob yeah that would definitely work better.

Comment: @djangonoob try something like this:

artists_by_movement2 = [{'Abstract Expressionism':['William Baziotes', 'Grace Hartigan', 'Norman Wilfred Lewis']},
                        {'Modern Art':['Alexander Calder', 'Lucian Freud']}, 
                        {'Cubism':['Peter Blume', 'Pablo Picasso']}]


##Because the movement & artist relationship is always there, it is implied by the structure and you don't need to explicitly use "movement" as a key.

Comment: @Reid thanks. that'll give me something to aim for as I keep hammering away at it. Still learning! I edited my question to reflect your advised format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to create a dict whose keys are the movements and values are a list of artists in that movement. All defaultdict does is auto-create a list when a new key is seen.

```
import collections

artist_movement = [
{'movement': 'Abstract Expressionism', 'artist': 'William Baziotes'}, 
{'movement': 'Modern Art', 'artist': 'Alexander Calder'}, 
{'movement': 'Abstract Expressionism', 'artist': 'Grace Hartigan'},
{'movement': 'Cubism', 'artist': 'Pablo Picasso'}, 
{'movement': 'Cubism', 'artist': 'Peter Blume'}, 
{'movement': 'Abstract Expressionism', 'artist': 'Norman Wilfred Lewis'},
{'movement': 'Modern Art', 'artist': 'Lucian Freud'}
]

artist_by_movement = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in artist_movement:
    artist_by_movement[d['movement']].append(d['artist'])
```

If you want a more traditional index to the original dictionaries (perhaps there is more interesting information in them) you could do

```
artist_by_movement = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in artist_movement:
    artist_by_movement[d['movement']].append(d)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much.