# Recursively merge dicts so that elements with shared key are combined into a list

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, union

I have two dicts that I want to merge:

```
a = {"name": "john",
     "phone":"123123123",
     "owns": {"cars": "Car 1", "motorbikes": "Motorbike 1"}}

b = {"name": "john",
     "phone":"123",
     "owns": {"cars": "Car 2"}}
```

If `a` and `b` have a common key on the same nesting level, the result should be a list, with both values in it, which is assigned as the value for the shared key.

The result should look like this:

```
{"name": "john",
 "phone":["123123123","123"],
 "owns": {"cars": ["Car 1", "Car 2"], "motorbikes": "Motorbike 1"}}
```

Using `a.update(b)` does not work since it overwrites the shared value of `a` with the shared value of `b`, such that result is something like this:

```
{'name': 'john', 'phone': '123', 'owns': {'cars': 'Car 2'}}
```

The goal is to merge the dicts without overwriting and to keep all information related to a specific key (in either of the dicts).

Comment: You want to merge the dicts by adding lists?

Comment: if `a` and `b` share a key with different values, the result should be a list, with both values in it and is assigned as value to the key

Comment: It would be good to explain that in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries of dictionaries merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key)

Comment: Some good answers here also and a better dupe - [merging Python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2365921/2823755)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With recursion, you can build a dictionary comprehension that accomplishes that.

This solution also takes into account that you might want to later merge more than two dictionaries, flattening the list of values in that case.

```
def update_merge(d1, d2):
    if isinstance(d1, dict) and isinstance(d2, dict):
        # Unwrap d1 and d2 in new dictionary to keep non-shared keys with **d1, **d2
        # Next unwrap a dict that treats shared keys
        # If two keys have an equal value, we take that value as new value
        # If the values are not equal, we recursively merge them
        return {
            **d1, **d2,
            **{k: d1[k] if d1[k] == d2[k] else update_merge(d1[k], d2[k])
            for k in {*d1} & {*d2}}
        }
    else:
        # This case happens when values are merged
        # It bundle values in a list, making sure
        # to flatten them if they are already lists
        return [
            *(d1 if isinstance(d1, list) else [d1]),
            *(d2 if isinstance(d2, list) else [d2])
        ]
```

Example:

```
a = {"name": "john", "phone":"123123123",
     "owns": {"cars": "Car 1", "motorbikes": "Motorbike 1"}}
b = {"name": "john", "phone":"123", "owns": {"cars": "Car 2"}}

update_merge(a, b)
# {'name': 'john',
#  'phone': ['123123123', '123'],
#  'owns': {'cars': ['Car 1', 'Car 2'], 'motorbikes': 'Motorbike 1'}}
```

Example with more than two objects merged:

```
a = {"name": "john"}
b = {"name": "jack"}
c = {"name": "joe"}

d = update_merge(a, b)
d = update_merge(d, c)

d # {'name': ['john', 'jack', 'joe']}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks. Can you shortly explain what exactly you are doing? I didn't full understand how your update_merge function works

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and recursion:

```
import itertools, sys
a = {"name": "john", "phone":"123123123", "owns": {"cars": "Car 1", "motorbikes": "Motorbike 1"}}
b = {"name": "john", "phone":"123", "owns": {"cars": "Car 2"}}
def condense(r):
  return r[0] if len(set(r)) == 1 else r

def update_dict(c, d):
  _v = {j:[c for _, c in h] for j, h in itertools.groupby(sorted(list(c.items())+list(d.items()), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
  return {j:update_dict(*e) if all(isinstance(i, dict) for i in e) else condense(e) for j, e in _v.items()}

print(update_dict(a, b))
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'john', 'owns': {'cars': ['Car 1', 'Car 2'], 'motorbikes': 'Motorbike 1'}, 'phone': ['123123123', '123']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets and things, can also merge any number of dictionaries:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

# Usage: merge(a, b, ...)
def merge(*args):
    # Make a copy of the input dicts, can be removed if you don't care about modifying
    # the original dicts.
    args = list(map(dict.copy, args))

    # Dict to store the result.
    out = {}

    for k in reduce(operator.and_, map(dict.keys, args)):  # Python 3 only, see footnotes.
        # Use `.pop()` so that after the all elements of shared keys have been combined,
        # `args` becomes a list of disjoint dicts that we can merge easily.
        vs = [d.pop(k) for d in args]

        if isinstance(vs[0], dict):
            # Recursively merge nested dicts
            common = merge(*vs)
        else:
            # Use a set to collect unique values
            common = set(vs)
            # If only one unique value, store that as is, otherwise use a list
            common = next(iter(common)) if len(common) == 1 else list(common)

        out[k] = common

    # Merge into `out` the rest of the now disjoint dicts
    for arg in args:
        out.update(arg)

    return out
```

Assuming that each dictionary to be merged have the same "structure", so `"owns"` can't be a list in `a` and a dict in `b`. Each element of the dict needs to be hashable as well since this method uses sets to aggregate unique values.

---

The following, only works in Python 3 since in Python 2, `dict.keys()` returns a plain old list.

```
reduce(operator.and_, map(dict.keys, args))
```

An alternative would be to add an additional `map()` to convert the lists to sets:

```
reduce(operator.and_, map(set, map(dict.keys, args)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized solution to support arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def _merge_dicts(dict_args):
    if not isinstance(dict_args[0], dict):
        return list(set(dict_args)) if len(set(dict_args)) > 1 else dict_args[0]
    keys = set().union(*dict_args)
    result = {key: 
              _merge_dicts(([d.get(key, None) for d in dict_args if d.get(key, None) is not None])) 
              for key in keys}
    return result
def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    return _merge_dicts(dict_args)

a = {"name": "john",
     "phone":"123123123",
     "owns": {"cars": "Car 1", "motorbikes": "Motorbike 1"}}

b = {"name": "john",
     "phone":"123",
     "owns": {"cars": "Car 2"}}

merge_dicts(a, b)
```

yields

```
{'name': 'john',
 'owns': {'motorbikes': 'Motorbike 1', 'cars': ['Car 2', 'Car 1']},
 'phone': ['123123123', '123']}
```