# merging dictionaries (of same key) which is containing a list in python 3.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to merge my dictionary with same key but it is a little bit different because one of the dictionary is containing a list. I am trying to get an output which will also give me a list back, if there is more than one value in the merged dictionary, like :

```
{'cartoon':['tom','jerry'],'film':['rose','jack','marry'],'serial':'little boy'}
```

I am using python 3.7. Is it possible to run the code without using defaultdict? I was also trying to write the print statement like:

```
print("{'cartoon':"+list(d1(key(value))+list(d2[key]+",'film':"+list(d1(key(value))+list(d2[key]+",'serial':"+list(d1(key(value))+list(d2(key(value))+"}"
```

but it did not work, so I wrote the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = {'cartoon': 'tom', 'film': 'rose'}
d2 = {'cartoon': 'jerry', 'film':['jack','marry'], 'serial' : 'little boy'}
new = defaultdict (list)
for char in (d1,d2):
    for key, value in char.iteritems():
        new[key].append(value)
print (new)
```

I am getting an error saying "AttributError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'.

Can anyone suggest it how can I edit this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? I believe that `iteritems` exists only in Python 2 (legacy Python). In either Python 2 or 3 you could use the `get` method of dictionaries to accomplish your purpose without `defaultdict`. Also, the indentation is off your your code: there is no indent between the two `for` loops.

Comment: use **.items()** instead of **.iteritems()**

Comment: `new[key].extend(value if isinstance(value, list) else [value])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively merge dicts so that elements with shared key are combined into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441027/recursively-merge-dicts-so-that-elements-with-shared-key-are-combined-into-a-lis)

Answer (score 0):

If you've ran this one Python 2, it would work, but since it looks like you're on Python 3, it doesn't, and you would have to replace this line:

```
    for key, value in char.iteritems():
```

With:

```
    for key, value in char.items():
```

Or the below as the full code would be much shorter:

```
print({k:(v+[d1[k]] if k in d1 else v) for k,v in d2.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

by list comprehension you can do :

```
d1 = {'cartoon': 'tom', 'film': 'rose'}
d2 = {'cartoon': 'jerry', 'film':['jack','marry'], 'serial' : 'little boy'}
#normalizing dictionaries
d1={k: v if isinstance(v , list) else [v] for k,v in d1.items()}
d2={k: v if isinstance(v , list) else [v] for k,v in d2.items()}

d3={k:list(set().union(d1.get(k, []),d2.get(k, [])))  for k in  (d1.keys()|d2.keys())}

print(d3)
```

output:

```
{'cartoon': ['jerry', 'tom'], 'film': ['marry', 'rose', 'jack'], 'serial': ['little boy']}
```

If you want to show single values as string you can do at the end:

```
d3={k:v if len(v)!=1 else v[0] for k,v in d3.items()}
```

output:

```
{'film': ['rose', 'marry', 'jack'], 'serial': 'little boy', 'cartoon': ['tom', 'jerry']}
```

Maybe this is what you want by saying "all in one line" :

```
d1 = {'cartoon': 'tom', 'film': 'rose'}
d2 = {'cartoon': 'jerry', 'film':['jack','marry'], 'serial' : 'little boy'}
#normalizing dictionaries
d1={k: v if isinstance(v , list) else [v] for k,v in d1.items()}
d2={k: v if isinstance(v , list) else [v] for k,v in d2.items()}

d3={k:list(set().union(d1.get(k, []),d2.get(k, []))) if len(set().union(d1.get(k, []),d2.get(k, [])))!=1 else list(set().union(d1.get(k, []),d2.get(k, [])))[0]   for k in  (d1.keys()|d2.keys())}

print(d3)
```

Comment: May I please know what is the purpose of union and get? I did not understand how 'd3' is working.

Comment: union is used because keys in dictionaries may be different so we need to iterate through all possible keys to make final dictionary

Comment: and get is just a try to get value in dictionary, so this way if a key is not present in one dictionary we can get rid of error

Comment: first union is combining values of two dictionaries

Comment: That makes more sense now. Thanks. But you also put "|" sign. What is the purpose of this one?

Comment: It is another union operator but the point is | operator only works for sets and we know dictonary.keys() is always a set

Comment: Thank you. If I do not want to write "little boy" inside [ ] because it is only one serial, is there any way?

Comment: if i do not want to write this line:                                                                               
  d3={k:list(set().union(d1.get(k, []),d2.get(k, [])))  for k in  (d1.keys()|d2.keys())}
how can I get the same result :   {'film': ['rose', 'marry', 'jack'], 'serial': 'little boy', 'cartoon': ['tom', 'jerry']}

Comment: you want all to be in one line?

Comment: yes, if i want to write the final merged dictionary in one line, how can I write that?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write your logic in one line isn't likely to yield any benefits. Also note `dict.iteritems` is deprecated in Python3 in favour of `dict.items`, which returns a *view*.

You can rewrite your logic more clearly using `list.extend` and a ternary statement. The functional solution looks obfuscated at first, but it permits an arbitrary number of input dictionaries, i.e. `(d1, d2, d3, ...)`, without resorting to an *explicit* nested loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
from operator import methodcaller

new = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('items'), (d1, d2))):
    new[key].extend([value] if not isinstance(value, list) else value)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {'cartoon': ['tom', 'jerry'],
#              'film': ['rose', 'jack', 'marry'],
#              'serial': ['little boy']})
```