# Merge two dicts with the same keys but add as another value (not replace)

Tags: python, dictionary

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365921/merging-python-dictionaries) seems to shown an example of appending to an array, not adding another value to a dict.

`dict_1 = {a: {price: 4000}, b: {price: 14000} }`

`dict_2 = {a: {discount: 0100}, b: {discount: 0400} }`

I would like to merge them to be:

```
merged_dict: { a: {
                   price: 4000, 
                   discount: 0100
                  }, 
               b: {
                   price: 14000, 
                   discount: 0400
               } 
              }
```

How to achieve that? Both dictionaries will always have the same keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension will solve this (I correctly formatted your dictionary definitions from the question, tested with Python 3.8.0):

```
>>> dict_1 = {'a': {'price': 4000}, 'b': {'price': 14000} }
>>> dict_2 = {'a': {'discount': 100}, 'b': {'discount': 400} }
>>> merged_dict = {k: { **dict_1[k], **dict_2[k] } for k in dict_2.keys()}
>>> merged_dict
{'a': {'price': 4000, 'discount': 100}, 'b': {'price': 14000, 'discount': 400}}
```

Comment: seems to work! care to explain what you did? mainly what the two asterisks do.

Comment: how would this be different if there were 3 dictionaries to merge?

Comment: You can merge it in one go with the others like that: `merged_dict = {k: { **dict_1[k], **dict_2[k], **dict_3[k] } for k in dict_2.keys()}` (this is still assuming they all have the same keys).