# merging several python dictionaries values ("sub"dictionaries)

Tags: python, dictionary

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277889/merge-two-dicts-with-the-same-keys-but-add-as-another-value-not-replace). And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365921/merging-python-dictionaries) seems to show an example of appending to an array, not adding another value to a sub-dict.

`dict_1 = {a: {price: 4000}, b: {price: 14000} }`

`dict_2 = {a: {discount: 0100}, b: {discount: 0400} }`

`dict_3 = {a: {amount: 41}, b: {amount: 522} }`

I would like to merge them to be:

```
merged_dict: { a: {
                   price: 4000, 
                   discount: 0100,
                   amount: 41
                  }, 
               b: {
                   price: 14000, 
                   discount: 0400,
                   amount: 522
               } 
              }
```

How to achieve that? And how would that be if there was en even longer list of dictionaries to merge? The dictionaries will always have the same keys (a, b).

I tried doing the same as in the first hyperlink but the `.items()` seem to make it unscalable.

Comment: What was the difficulty when you tried to do this? Have you tried writing something like: `for k in dict_1: merged_dict[k]['price'] = dict_1[k]['price']; for k in dict_2: merged_dict[k]['discount'] = dict_2[k]['discount']`, etc.?

Comment: I also don't understand what is the difference between this question and your earlier question you've linked, other than here you are showing 3 input dictionaries instead of 2.

Comment: ```merged_dict = {k: { **dict_1[k], **dict_2[k] } for k in dict_2.keys()}``` this has two dictionaries, and loops over the keys of the second dict only. I can't think of how to do this, since which dict should I iterate over?

Comment: Over all of them, in another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize this kind of merge by placing your dictionaries in a list and creating the merged dictionary in a comprehension:

```
dict_1 = {"a": {"price": 4000}, "b": {"price": 14000} }

dict_2 = {"a": {"discount": 100}, "b": {"discount": 400} }

dict_3 = {"a": {"amount": 41}, "b": {"amount": 522} }

dicts  = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]

merged = { k:dict(kv for d in dicts for kv in d[k].items()) for k in dicts[0] }

print(merged)
{'a': {'price': 4000, 'discount': 100, 'amount': 41}, 
 'b': {'price': 14000, 'discount': 400, 'amount': 522}}
```